# Why using StatelessWidget works fine here?

Tags: flutter, dart

Just started playing around with dart and flutter today. I'm trying to fully grasp the basics and I have trouble understanding why the following works fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatelessWidget {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _textKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState<String>>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            key: _textKey,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(_textKey.currentState.value)));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation), they are using a `StatefulWidget` with a `State` where I'm simply using a `StatelessWidget`. Is there a reason why the `StatelessWidget` works in this case and why should we be using a `StatefulWidget` ?

Comment: It works fine because there is nothing wrong with it. If you want to have *dynamic data*, then you will need a Stateful Widget. You are not changing the *state* here at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Form`](http://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Form-class.html) class is a `StatefulWidget`

Note the inheritance:

> Object  > Diagnosticable > DiagnosticableTree > Widget > StatefulWidget > Form

All the stateful work in this example is contained within the scope of the `Form`.

If you wanted to maintain state within a portion `MyCustomForm`, but outside `Form`, then you would have to change `MyCustomForm` to a `StatefulWidget`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no obligation to use stateful widget. You decide whether your class needs to extend a stateful widget or stateless widget.

A Stateful widget is used when you are sure that there will be change of data in your class and need to rebuild your UI (Like the flutter hello world app).
on the other hand , Stateless widget is used when you know that your class won't change UI (a splash screen with a single image for example).

In this example , both can do the job perfectly. There is no change of data so stateless can be used , also a stateful can be used.

Read more about [stateful widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) and [stateless widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html) and other solutions of state management